# nuget installs a package that find-package can't find

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Trying to fix a problem, This worked for me:

```
Install-Package NuGet.Manifest.Schema -Version 2.0.0
```

Then, curious to know if there were other versions, I tried find-package:

```
find-package nuget -allversions -includeprerelease
```

which returned:

> NuGet.Core                          NuGet.VisualStudio
>   NuGet.Client                        NuGet.CommandLine
>   NuGet.Server                        NuGet.Configuration
>   JetBrains.NuGet.Ultimate            NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types           NuGet.Protocol.Core.v2
>   NuGet.Protocol.VisualStudio
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShe... Nugety.Nuget
>   NugetyCore.Nuget                    MsBuild.NuGet.Pack
>   Tvl.NuGet.BuildTasks                NuGet.Services.Platform.Client
>   NuGet.Lucene.Web                    NuGet.Lucene
>   NuGetTest.Common.Web.Nuget
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.0397859

But the package I just installed is not listed.  That surprised me!

Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

The [NuGet.Manifest.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Manifest.Schema) NuGet package has been unlisted.

[Unlisted packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/policies/deleting-packages) are still available to be installed, if you specify the version, since otherwise they would break NuGet package restore for projects that installed them when they were still listed.

Unlisted NuGet packages will not be returned in searches.

Comment: OK I get it.  In this case I was looking for an up-to-date nuget xsd that includes the "packages" element.  Version 2.0.0 that I installed is missing that.